# matplotlib imshow display values of matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, adjacency-matrix, imshow

i have a matrix of 10*10 now i want to insert values on my image plot which is plotted by imshow from matplot library but I dont know how.the code is as below

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
img = ax.imshow(df7)
ax.set_xticks([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
ax.set_yticks([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
fig.colorbar(img)
```

[image]

Comment: You can use seaborn which handles that for you `import seaborn as sns; sns.heatmap(df7)` so you don't need all `ax.set_` commands.

Comment: i want to show values of each block in my plot but it still does not work with seaborn

Comment: Did you try the `annot=True` option? Did you remove the second `plt.imshow()`?

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you want. `labels` is not defined in your code. Is your problem about x and y ticks? the colorbar? "show values of each block" is not clear

Comment: `plt.style.use("dark_background")` to set the background black and the tick labels white.

Answer (score 0):

I must use seaborn and matplotlib libraries and change my code as below :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
img = sns.heatmap(df7,annot=True) 
ax.set_xticks([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
ax.set_yticks([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
```